# Why "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weka.core.NominalAttributeInfo" error in Java weka Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, machine-learning, weka

I am creating a machine learning app in Android using weka, but I get an error while creating classifier from pre-trained model.
Following is my Android code snippet:

```
AssetManager am = this.getAssets();
InputStream stnonstmodel = am.open("stnonstgoodmodel.model");
Classifier  cls= (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(stnonstmodel); // I am getting error on this line
```

Also, it must be noted that the classifier returns null whenever used after this line.

Printing cls.toString() gives "Classifier not built" in Android.
My error log is :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weka.core.NominalAttributeInfo
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:309)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:2263)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1641)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:657)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNewObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1782)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonPrimitiveContent(ObjectInputStream.java:761)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1983)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1940)
.               
.               //Similar error lines//
.
```

Any guesses as to why this is happening?